# How to add value to attribute of all objects which are in list

Tags: python

I'm fighting with some problem. Imagine that we have object:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
       self.value = value
```

Then we create few objects and add them to the list:

```
for obj in range(10):
    L.append(A())
```

Then I wanna add value to attribute of all objects in the list.

It is easy when we create just a function:

```
 def add(self, List):
     for objs in List:
         objs.value += 1
```

,but I'm looking for nicer method. I have tried with lambda and list comprehension, something like this:

```
 add = lambda some_list: [obj.value+1 for obj in some_list]
```

,but it is not work at all.

Do you have any idea how to solve this in pythonic way? Thanks!

Comment: No, there is not really a cleaner way to do this.  You need to perform an assignment, which is a statement in Python.  So, you cannot inline it.  Your best bet is to use a for-loop.

Comment: In what way is making a list you are just going to throw away in order to perform an operation on the elements of an existing list "nicer"?

Comment: What do you mean by "but it is not work at all."? Any errors?

Comment: The `def` **is** the Pythonic way -- clear, simple, explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to write:

```
add = functools.partial(map, lambda obj : obj.value + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created list 'L' of objects, following code worked for me

```
[obj.value += 1 for obj in L]
```

Now attribute of each object in 'L' will have incremented value